# Jquery Sortable with dynamic lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a piece of script which works fine but only relates to one `<ul>`.

```
$("#sortme").sortable({
    update : function () {
        serial = $('#sortme').sortable('serialize');
        $.ajax({
            url: "includes/sort_menu.php",
            type: "post",
            data: serial,
            error: function(){
                alert("theres an error");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This basically arranges **sections** that later need to be populated. For each section a new `ul` is created and the next items are placed in the corresponding section.

To make the new items sortable I have used the following code when appending the new item to the section:

```
$('ul.sortable.'+section+'').sortable();
```

This works fine and allows me to reorder the items within the specified sections.

As this bit of code is contained within a function called when an item is added to the section my problem arises that I want to save the order (as happens in the top script). So far I have been unable to fire a similar function when the items have been reordered.

How do I go about activating a function when I reorder the specific list ?

Comment: have you tried `sortable({ appendTo: element })` and `sortable("refresh")` methods? http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: Where about in the code do I add this - at present it throws an error if added to the `$('ul.sortable.'+section+'').sortable('refresh');` bit of script.

Comment: i can't really tell by just looking at your code, you need to add the html context